Lightning component warning/error in flexipage
As i need one component(button) to be displayed in the record page, but receiving the following error/warning in Lightning page:
"this related list cannot be displayed because its not in the current page layout".


Even thought i have added required relate list("Similar Insights") in "Insights" page layout.
So,can you please help me in resolving this issue?
Thanks,
Vidya

The layout needs to be assigned for the contextual user via a page layout assignment for their profile.

Hi @PhilW, yes this is the only one layout for Insight object and it is assigned to all profiles.
